# C++ Exam being Weird

Tags: c++, debugging, c++98

This is an exam question I got.
It needs us to write down the output of this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Hello {
protected:
 string nameString;
public:
 Hello(string name) :nameString(name) {};
 string getName() {
  return nameString;
 };
 virtual string hello() = 0;
};

class Ohio :public Hello {
public:
 Ohio(string name) :Hello(name) {};
 virtual string hello() {
  return "Ohio, ";
 }
 ~Ohio() {
  cout << "Ohio Bye, " << nameString << endl;
 }
};

class Aloha :public Hello {
public:
 Aloha(string name) :Hello(name) {};


 string getName() {
  return "[" + nameString + "]";
 }

 virtual string hello() {
  return "Aloha, ";
 }
 ~Aloha() {
  cout << "Aloha Bye, " << nameString << endl;
 }

};

class HelloPrinter {
public:
 void print(Hello* Helo) {
  cout << Helo->hello() << Helo->getName() << endl;
 }
};

template<class T>
class objectPrinter {
public:
 void print(T& HelObj) {
  cout << HelObj.hello() << HelObj.getName() << endl;
 }
};

int main() {
 cout << __cplusplus << endl;
 
 Hello* hi = new Ohio("John");
 HelloPrinter Hp;
 Hp.print(hi);

 Aloha eloha("Peter");
 Hp.print(&eloha);

 Hello& hob = Aloha("Bob"); // THE ERROR
 Hp.print(&hob);

 objectPrinter<Aloha> objectPtr;
 Aloha song("Jane");
 objectPtr.print(song);
 
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

The code provided by the question has a compile error in it, and I have send an email to my professor to confirm that the question has an error, but my professor said that I don't have enough knowledge to say that and I need to study more. But clearly there is an error in the code. **I'm using C98 for compiling**. The weirder part comes below:

```
// OUTPUT
Ohio, John
Aloha, Peter
Aloha Bye, Bob
Aloha, Bob
Aloha, [Jane]
Aloha Bye, Jane
Aloha Bye, Bob
Aloha Bye,Peter
```

Where 'Bye' means the destructor is being called, and I have no idea why Bob's **destructor is being called before the constructor.** It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Print the value of `this` in the constructor and destructor, not just simple text.  You will see what object is being created and destroyed.  Also, the code is flawed, as you do not have a virtual destructor in the base class.

Comment: the question is unclear. You say it has an error but at the same time it produces output. The code you posted does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/n6rEo6f55

Comment: You should indeed state clearly which error you get. In any case, learning to code in an obsolete language C++98 that is a quarter of a century old (!) is a futile endeavor. Please target at least C++11, which is lightyears ahead. Also, which compiler specifically are you using?

Comment: your instructor is probably using visual studio which allows the non-standard binding of a temporary to a non-const reference: https://godbolt.org/z/T7cEzWWah. Making the reference `const` fixes the compilation with other compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/6eqPhWcf7

Comment: *but my professor said that I don't have enough knowledge to say that* -- So the professor is saying you don't have the knowledge to go to a reputable online compiler, copy and paste the code there, and compile it?   If I were teaching that class, I would say "hold on...yes, you're right.   I will make the update."

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I can confirm that the code doesn't compile is not my problem now. And I'll email this post to my professor, if you have any words to say to my professor, you can freely type it here(no insults of course :D ).

Comment: @Jimmy -- Also point out that the base class does not have a virtual destructor.  So if you had the line (which is really missing) `delete hi;`, then that would be an issue, since deleting a pointer to a derived using a pointer to base is undefined behavior without the base class having a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Jimmy -- If your professor is using Visual Studio, turning up the warning level to `/W4` and recompiling will produce a warning diagnostic that the line of code that others have pointed out is not standard C++.  It's only a warning in Visual C++, but it is an error in the other compilers (and an error in C++ anyway).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie since VS2017, you can pass `/permissive-` to turn of the non-conforming extensions that are on by default

Comment: I think it is worth noting that the purpose of this exam is PROBABLY not to verify that the student can frob a compiler, but that the student can read and understand code. _**Actually compiling the code is not necessary to answer the exam**_.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie Thanks for pointing out the missing virtual destructor, and the Visual Studio warning level thing, what a valuable lesson. 
@ AlanBirtles Thanks for fixing the code by adding const to the variable and the function, and it worked out perfectly.
@ UlrichEckhardt Thank you for directing me for using C++11, I thought everyone is using C++98 :)
@ 463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for helping me to confirm the code does not compile in normal circumstances.

Comment: @Dúthomhas except that the program is ill-formed. It *doesn't have* a meaning

Comment: @Caleth Except introductory C++ professors don't care, and getting a bunch of people online to give him (or her) grief about strict conformance when the code compiles just fine in VS is just asking for a problematic relationship with the person you want a good grade from -- _especially_ if the test has nothing to do with compiling!

Comment: @Dúthomhas but the behaviour that the test is asking about is not documented *anywhere*, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Dúthomhas where's the extra `Aloha` object? The standard doesn't say, because it forbids that code. Microsoft's documentation doesn't say. A *guess* is that `hob` is bound to an `Aloha`, copy-constructed from the prvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question is "This program is ill-formed". I don't think this is the answer the professor is expecting.

The C++ standards do not specify any behaviour for ill-formed programs. In a very real sense, it is not a C++ program.

It also looks like [Microsoft don't define](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-referencebinding-enforce-reference-binding-rules?view=msvc-170) what Visual Studio does with that code, only that it does *something*, and that something isn't compliant with ISO C++.

If you instead had `const Hello& hob = Aloha("Bob");`, there wouldn't be a spurious "Aloha Bye, Bob" in the output, because the `Aloha` wouldn't be destroyed on that line.

Similarly `Hello bob = Aloha("Bob");` is correctly rejected by Visual Studio.